# Inequality using integration by parts.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have shown easily that for a function $f$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0, \int_{a}^{b}f^2=1$, that:

$$\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)f'(x)=-1/2$$

But how can I now show that:

$$\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)^2 \int_{a}^{b}x^2f(x)^2 > 1/4$$

I'm sure a hint will suffice here. I'm not sure what the natural choice is here as far as integration by parts goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by FH93, [Cauchy-Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) shows that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^bf'(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\int_a^bx^2f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x
&\ge\left(\int_a^bxf(x)f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2\\
&=\left(-\frac12\right)^2\\
&=\frac14\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Cauchy-Schwarz can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{align}
0
&\le\int_a^b\left(\lambda xf(x)-\mu f'(x)\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lambda^2\int_a^bx^2f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x+\mu^2\int_a^bf'(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x
-2\lambda\mu\int_a^bxf(x)f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int_a^bx^2f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\int_a^bf'(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&-2\left(\int_a^bx^2f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\int_a^bf'(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}\int_a^bxf(x)f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
where we set $\lambda=\left(\int_a^bf'(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}$ and $\mu=\left(\int_a^bx^2f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}$.

Thus, the inequality is strict unless
$$
\lambda xf(x)-\mu f'(x)=0\tag{3}
$$
which means
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=-2kx\tag{4}
$$
and therefore,
$$
f(x)=ce^{-kx^2}\tag{5}
$$
However, for any $f$ given in $(5)$, $f(a)=0$ or $f(b)=0$ could only hold if $c=0$, but then $f$ would be identically $0$ and then we would not have
$$
\int_a^bxf(x)f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac12\tag{6}
$$

Therefore, the inequality is strict.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality trivialises it.

$\left(\displaystyle\int_a^b fg\right)^2 \leq \left(\displaystyle\int_a^b f^2 \right)\left(\displaystyle\int_a^b g^2\right)$

Comment: Do we even need continuity of $f'$ actually?

Comment: No we don't, you're quite right. Integrability will suffice.

Comment: Problem is, that we are trying to get strict inequality here.

Comment: Consider the conditions under which equality arises separately.

Comment: As I recall, we need $f$ to be a multiple of $g$, correct?

Comment: Check the inequality for $f(x)=ce^{-x^2}$ where $c$ is chosen so that $$\int_a^b2x^2f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac12$$ I believe that equality holds in that case. Of course, the boundary conditions are not met for finite $a$ and $b$.

Comment: That doesn't satisfy the conditions of the problem. It's also unclear why the Cauchy Schwarz inequality is strict still. If I assume that $f'$ is some multiple of $xf(x)$, then, assuming that multiple is not 0 (I checked, and it can't be anyways), it boils down to showing that $\int_{a}^{b} xf(x)$ cannot be 0, but I'm not sure why this is true.